# When to call SELinux.restorecon()?

Tags: android, selinux

The Android open source code contains code such as this. Can anyone explain why and under which circumstances it is necessary to do SELinux.restorecon(File)?

```
    // If Encrypted file systems is enabled or disabled, this call will return the
    // correct directory.
    mBaseStateDir = new File(Environment.getSecureDataDirectory(), "backup");
    mBaseStateDir.mkdirs();
    if (!SELinux.restorecon(mBaseStateDir)) {
        Slog.e(TAG, "SELinux restorecon failed on " + mBaseStateDir);
    }
```

Can we do it too often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELinux [`restorecon`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/restorecon.8.html) is used to restore the default security contexts on some files/dir.

The thing (which is not obvious) is that we also use it to *apply* context changes, and/or to ensure that the file contexts are as you expect.

Usually, we define/override default security contexts using [`semanage-fcontext`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-fcontext.8.html), and then run `restorecon` to relabel files according to these new defaults.

Here the code tries to relabel `mBaseStateDir` but fails to do so. It could be that :

- there is no policy supporting the default context associated to that directory (given it's path)
- `mBaseStateDir` is mislabeled (context type is not apllicable)
- user/process running that code doesn't have the sufficient permission to relabel the directory (even it just created it).

Comment: OK, thanks for info. But when typically is it necessary to do this? When does the context get distorted? Under what circumstances (in Android) could that happen?

Comment: The answer describes the typical use case, which is restoring default (or applying recently changed default) security contexts. When does the context get distorted, well this is another question for which there are probably a lot of possible answers. I would say that app developers (not android dev) could mislabel files inadvertently because they don't care much about doing things properly but just fix their AVC denials. It's normal though that the Android system oftenly checks that the labeling is both applicable _and_ correctly applied given the currently loaded SELInux policies.